# How to push code to root of git repository (GitHub)

Tags: eclipse, git, svn, version-control, github

I am very new to git and have been facing the problem below for 4-5 days now.

I have a project that I want to share on GitHub and I created a repo (https://github.com/jitix/cfs/tree/master/cfs) for the same. 
Here is what I did:

1. Checked out the code from svn using Eclipse (Juno).
2. Removed svn related files and 'cleaned' the folder by doing Team > Disconnect.
3. Created a local git repository (using both via eclipse and cli on different occasions).
4. Added appropriate .gitignore file.
5. Committed the code into the local repo (somehow eclipse moves the folder there, but not an issue). Eclipse made me choose the $repo/cfs as the folder where the code is committed. I could not commit it to $repo.

Now I want to push it into GitHub. Tried out the following:
Method 1 (eclipse):

1. Team > Remote > Push
2. Use refs/heads/master as both source ref and dest ref and commit.

Method 2 (cli from the $repo/cfs directory):

1. git remote add origin jitix@https://github.com/jitix/cfs.git
2. git push -u origin master

**Issue:**
In both cases, I am getting the cfs directory under the GitHub repo, not at the root (as most projects have). Also, each folder has a .. link to the parent folder in it (something that I have never seen on GitHub, and something that does not happen if I push using svn).

I checked out my code from svn, created a local repo and committed the code into

Comment: did you solve you problem?

Comment: I am looking for the answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the git repository *inside* the folder that you want to upload. You've created it one level above the cfs folder and then pushed that, you want to run `git init` while inside `cfs` and then go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try in commandline instead using eclipse and follow the steps that GitHub recommends.

Go inside the directory of your project and type:

1. git init
2. git commit -a -m "first commit"
3. git remote add origin jitix@https://github.com/jitix/cfs.git
4. git push -u origin master

It should work, although is pretty much what you were doing.